# spring-boot mongodb when i add @Indexed(unique = true) spring boot project not starting

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I have a model class and some fields. I want to make some fields unique but when i add this @Indexed(unique = true) spring boot app giving error like this:

```
Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDatabaseFactoryDependentConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate]: Factory method 'mongoTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1, userName='rootuser', source='admin', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties=<hidden>}; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1, userName='rootuser', source='admin', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties=<hidden>}
```

But if I remove "indexed", app is starting.

My model class:

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Document
public class User {
    @Id
    private String id;

    @Size(max = 50)
    private String name;

    @Indexed(unique = true)
    @Size(max = 20)
    private String username;

  // @Indexed(unique = true)
    private String email;

    private Role role;

   // private Gender gender;

   

    private String password;

    private List<String> followerIdsList;
    private List<String> followingIdsList;

    private boolean deleted;


    public User(String username, String email, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }

}
```

Full stacktrace:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.11\bin\java.exe" -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -noverify -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=49823:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1.3\bin" -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dspring.jmx.enabled=true -Dspring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain -Dspring.application.admin.enabled=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath D:\SoftwareProjects\Backend\trakya_confession_be\target\classes;C:\Users\Gurkan\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb\2.6.1\spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-2.6.1.jar;C:\Users\Gurkan\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\2.6.1\spring-boot-starter-2.6.1.jar;C:\Users\Gurkan\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\2.6.1\spring-boot-starter-logging-2.6.1.jar;C:\Users\Gurkan\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.2.7\logback-classic-1.2.7.jar;C:\Users\Gurkan\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.2.7\logback-core-1.2.7.jar;C:\Users\Gurkan\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.14.1\log4j-to-slf4j-2.14.1.jar;C:\Users\Gurkan\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.14.1\log4j-api-2.14.1.jar;C:\Users\Gurkan\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.32\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.32.jar;C:\Users\Gurkan\.m2\repository\jakarta\annotation\jakarta.annotation-api\1.3.5\jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar;C:\Users\Gurkan\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.29\snakeyaml-1.29.jar;C:\Users\Gurkan\.m2\repository\org\mongodb\mongodb-driver-sync\4.4.0\mongodb-driver-sync-4.4.0.jar;C:\Users\Gurkan\.m2\repository\org\mongodb\bson\4.4.0\bson-4.4.0.jar;C:\Users\Gurkan\.m2\repository\org\mongodb\mongodb-driver-core\4.4.0\mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0.jar;C:\Users\Gurkan\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-mongodb\3.3.0\spring-data-mongodb-3.3.0.jar;C:\Users\Gurkan\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\5.3.13\spring-tx-5.3.13.jar;C:\Users\Gurkan\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\5.3.13\spring-context-5.3.13.jar;C:\Users\Gurkan\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\5.3.13\spring-beans-5.3.13.jar;C:\Users\Gurkan\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\5.3.13\spring-expression-5.3.13.jar;C:\Users\Gurkan\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-commons\2.6.0\spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar;C:\Users\Gurkan\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.32\slf4j-api-1.7.32.jar;C:\Users\Gurkan\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-security\2.6.1\spring-boot-starter-security-2.6.1.jar;C:\Users\Gurkan\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\5.3.13\spring-aop-5.3.13.jar;C:\Users\Gurkan\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-config\5.6.0\spring-security-config-5.6.0.jar;C:\Users\Gurkan\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-web\5.6.0\spring-security-web-5.6.0.jar;C:\Users\Gurkan\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-validation\2.6.1\spring-boot-starter-validation-2.6.1.jar;C:\Users\Gurkan\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-el\9.0.55\tomcat-embed-el-9.0.55.jar;C:\Users\Gurkan\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\validator\hibernate-validator\6.2.0.Final\hibernate-validator-6.2.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\Gurkan\.m2\repository\jakarta\validation\jakarta.validation-api\2.0.2\jakarta.validation-api-2.0.2.jar;C:\Users\Gurkan\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.4.2.Final\jboss-logging-3.4.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\Gurkan\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.5.1\classmate-1.5.1.jar;C:\Users\Gurkan\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-web\2.6.1\spring-boot-starter-web-2.6.1.jar;C:\Users\Gurkan\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-json\2.6.1\spring-boot-starter-json-2.6.1.jar;C:\Users\Gurkan\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.13.0\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.13.0.jar;C:\Users\Gurkan\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.13.0\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.13.0.jar;C:\Users\Gurkan\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.13.0\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.13.0.jar;C:\Users\Gurkan\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-tomcat\2.6.1\spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.6.1.jar;C:\Users\Gurkan\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-core\9.0.55\tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar;C:\Users\Gurkan\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-websocket\9.0.55\tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.55.jar;C:\Users\Gurkan\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\5.3.13\spring-web-5.3.13.jar;C:\Users\Gurkan\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\5.3.13\spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar;C:\Users\Gurkan\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-devtools\2.6.1\spring-boot-devtools-2.6.1.jar;C:\Users\Gurkan\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\2.6.1\spring-boot-2.6.1.jar;C:\Users\Gurkan\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\2.6.1\spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.1.jar;C:\Users\Gurkan\.m2\repository\org\projectlombok\lombok\1.18.22\lombok-1.18.22.jar;C:\Users\Gurkan\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\5.3.13\spring-core-5.3.13.jar;C:\Users\Gurkan\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\5.3.13\spring-jcl-5.3.13.jar;C:\Users\Gurkan\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-core\5.6.0\spring-security-core-5.6.0.jar;C:\Users\Gurkan\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-crypto\5.6.0\spring-security-crypto-5.6.0.jar;C:\Users\Gurkan\.m2\repository\io\jsonwebtoken\jjwt\0.9.1\jjwt-0.9.1.jar;C:\Users\Gurkan\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.13.0\jackson-databind-2.13.0.jar;C:\Users\Gurkan\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.13.0\jackson-annotations-2.13.0.jar;C:\Users\Gurkan\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.13.0\jackson-core-2.13.0.jar com.gucarsoft.trakya_confession_be.TrakyaConfessionBeApplication
17:12:48.616 [Thread-0] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader - Created RestartClassLoader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader@fd1df96

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.6.1)

2021-12-13 17:12:48.889  INFO 4892 --- [  restartedMain] c.g.t.TrakyaConfessionBeApplication      : Starting TrakyaConfessionBeApplication using Java 11.0.11 on DESKTOP-1OA1152 with PID 4892 (D:\SoftwareProjects\Backend\trakya_confession_be\target\classes started by Gurkan in D:\SoftwareProjects\Backend\trakya_confession_be)
2021-12-13 17:12:48.890  INFO 4892 --- [  restartedMain] c.g.t.TrakyaConfessionBeApplication      : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-12-13 17:12:48.939  INFO 4892 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2021-12-13 17:12:48.939  INFO 4892 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2021-12-13 17:12:49.430  INFO 4892 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data MongoDB repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-12-13 17:12:49.436  INFO 4892 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 3 ms. Found 0 MongoDB repository interfaces.
2021-12-13 17:12:49.737  INFO 4892 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2021-12-13 17:12:49.743  INFO 4892 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-12-13 17:12:49.743  INFO 4892 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.55]
2021-12-13 17:12:49.791  INFO 4892 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-12-13 17:12:49.791  INFO 4892 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 851 ms
2021-12-13 17:12:50.039  INFO 4892 --- [  restartedMain] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Cluster created with settings {hosts=[localhost:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms'}
2021-12-13 17:12:50.075  INFO 4892 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:1, serverValue:201}] to localhost:27017
2021-12-13 17:12:50.075  INFO 4892 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:202}] to localhost:27017
2021-12-13 17:12:50.076  INFO 4892 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=localhost:27017, type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=13, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=13775300}
2021-12-13 17:12:50.138  INFO 4892 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2021-12-13 17:12:50.217  WARN 4892 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDatabaseFactoryDependentConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate]: Factory method 'mongoTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1, userName='rootuser', source='admin', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties=<hidden>}; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1, userName='rootuser', source='admin', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties=<hidden>}
2021-12-13 17:12:50.221  INFO 4892 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2021-12-13 17:12:50.229  INFO 4892 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-12-13 17:12:50.247 ERROR 4892 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDatabaseFactoryDependentConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate]: Factory method 'mongoTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1, userName='rootuser', source='admin', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties=<hidden>}; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1, userName='rootuser', source='admin', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties=<hidden>}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1290) ~[spring-boot-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at com.gucarsoft.trakya_confession_be.TrakyaConfessionBeApplication.main(TrakyaConfessionBeApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate]: Factory method 'mongoTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1, userName='rootuser', source='admin', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties=<hidden>}; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1, userName='rootuser', source='admin', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties=<hidden>}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1, userName='rootuser', source='admin', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties=<hidden>}; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1, userName='rootuser', source='admin', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties=<hidden>}
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MongoExceptionTranslator.java:140) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.potentiallyConvertRuntimeException(MongoTemplate.java:2906) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.execute(MongoTemplate.java:557) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.DefaultIndexOperations.execute(DefaultIndexOperations.java:214) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.DefaultIndexOperations.ensureIndex(DefaultIndexOperations.java:121) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.createIndex(MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.java:156) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.checkForAndCreateIndexes(MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.java:146) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.checkForIndexes(MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.java:130) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.<init>(MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.java:95) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.<init>(MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.java:72) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.<init>(MongoTemplate.java:243) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.mongo.MongoDatabaseFactoryDependentConfiguration.mongoTemplate(MongoDatabaseFactoryDependentConfiguration.java:63) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1, userName='rootuser', source='admin', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties=<hidden>}
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator.wrapException(SaslAuthenticator.java:273) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator.getNextSaslResponse(SaslAuthenticator.java:137) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator.access$100(SaslAuthenticator.java:48) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator$1.run(SaslAuthenticator.java:63) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator$1.run(SaslAuthenticator.java:57) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator.doAsSubject(SaslAuthenticator.java:280) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator.authenticate(SaslAuthenticator.java:57) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultAuthenticator.authenticate(DefaultAuthenticator.java:55) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.authenticate(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:207) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.finishHandshake(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:81) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:185) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.UsageTrackingInternalConnection.open(UsageTrackingInternalConnection.java:54) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$PooledConnection.open(DefaultConnectionPool.java:538) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$OpenConcurrencyLimiter.openWithConcurrencyLimit(DefaultConnectionPool.java:914) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$OpenConcurrencyLimiter.openOrGetAvailable(DefaultConnectionPool.java:855) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool.get(DefaultConnectionPool.java:173) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool.get(DefaultConnectionPool.java:162) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServer.getConnection(DefaultServer.java:101) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.binding.ClusterBinding$ClusterBindingConnectionSource.getConnection(ClusterBinding.java:175) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.ClientSessionBinding$SessionBindingConnectionSource.getConnection(ClientSessionBinding.java:188) ~[mongodb-driver-sync-4.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.OperationHelper.withConnectionSource(OperationHelper.java:543) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.OperationHelper.withConnection(OperationHelper.java:536) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.CreateIndexesOperation.execute(CreateIndexesOperation.java:192) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.CreateIndexesOperation.execute(CreateIndexesOperation.java:72) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$DelegateOperationExecutor.execute(MongoClientDelegate.java:212) ~[mongodb-driver-sync-4.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.executeCreateIndexes(MongoCollectionImpl.java:848) ~[mongodb-driver-sync-4.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.createIndexes(MongoCollectionImpl.java:831) ~[mongodb-driver-sync-4.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.createIndexes(MongoCollectionImpl.java:826) ~[mongodb-driver-sync-4.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.createIndex(MongoCollectionImpl.java:811) ~[mongodb-driver-sync-4.4.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.DefaultIndexOperations.lambda$ensureIndex$0(DefaultIndexOperations.java:131) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.execute(MongoTemplate.java:555) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    ... 39 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 18 (AuthenticationFailed): 'Authentication failed.' on server localhost:27017. The full response is {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "Authentication failed.", "code": 18, "codeName": "AuthenticationFailed"}
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.ProtocolHelper.getCommandFailureException(ProtocolHelper.java:198) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveCommandMessageResponse(InternalStreamConnection.java:418) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:342) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.sendAndReceive(CommandHelper.java:96) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:44) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator.sendSaslStart(SaslAuthenticator.java:228) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SaslAuthenticator.getNextSaslResponse(SaslAuthenticator.java:135) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0.jar:na]
    ... 68 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Please add the full stacktrace (as code) to your question.

Comment: I added the stacktrace

Comment: Does it actually work when not using `@Indexed`?  So not only starting but a working application? As it looks like to fail when connecting to Mongo to do an action (create the index), so I would expect it to fail using the application (so not just starting it!) with the same failure. As i appears you aren't allowed to connect.